# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Game Development breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  3         16
Users destroyed                                   7          0
Users deleted                                     3          0
Users contacted                                   7          0
User banned from review                           1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           387        760
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               63         37
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         91         87
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              167        223
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               293      2,653
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              239        300
Tags merged                                       9          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            10          0
Tag synonyms created                              6          0
Tag highlight language set                        1          0
Questions reopened                               58          0
Questions protected                              10          9
Questions migrated                                4          0
Questions merged                                  3          0
Questions flagged⁴                               17        598
Questions closed                                947         38
Question flags handled⁴                         330        285
Posts unlocked                                    1          3
Posts undeleted                                  10         93
Posts locked                                      4         68
Posts deleted⁵                                  398      2,610
Posts bumped                                      0      8,733
Comments undeleted                               25          0
Comments flagged                                 18      1,399
Comments deleted⁶                             2,341      2,264
Comment flags handled                           363      1,054
Bounties canceled                                 1          0
Answers flagged                                  49        662
Answer flags handled                            598        113
All comments on a post moved to chat             14          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...